# Android studio launches application without reinstalling it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I am working on an android app using both JDK and NDK, and it looks like I always need to uninstall the application in order for Android Studio to install the APK after changes are made.

I tried unchecking the "Skip installation if APK has not changed" checkbox, but this hasn't helped.

I am working under Android Studio 2.1.3 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: "it looks like" -- please explain, **in detail**, how you came to this conclusion. With Android Studio 2.x, Instant Run is enabled by default, and this will patch your existing APK (more or less) with changes.

Comment: @CommonsWare well I tried adding logs in `onCreate` and `onTouch` events to try it, and I couldn't get anything in the log. I also tried adding a TextView, and that didn't show up either.
I did however get the changes to work after uninstalling the app. I also noticed that in the bottom bar, when I run the app, only "Launching activity" is displayed, and at no time does "Installing APK" seem to show up, unless I uninstall the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be its with Instant run...
make sure its off..

Reference :https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html